# parse_str on an object instead of global namespace

Tags: php, security

Normally using `parse_str('name=me&hungry=yes')` will make a variable `$name` and `hungry` be equal to `'me'` and `'yes'` respectively.

The problem with using this function is that I'm running it through user input and feel uncomfortable making sure I can't get any attacks because of this, since the variables are being put on the global namespace.

Is there any way to make this functionality only put values into a given variable? For example something like `parse_str('name=me&hungry=yes', $obj)` will make `obj` be equal to

```
array('name' => 'me', 'hungry' => 'yes');
```

Comment: What's wrong with <code>parse_str('name=me&hungry=yes', $obj):</code>? On reading the manual it should work as you would like. The second argument will be passed by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only for example, but exactly. See [`parse_str`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/parse_str), especially the examples.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `parse_str()` will be an array of the params.

Answer (score 0):

`parse_str($string,$newarray)`

$newarray is the array you can work on from there